# What is the difference between 0/1 and true/false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

Recently I was trying to accomplish a feature for my app. I needed to use boolean values to turn on or off features.

I tried this:

.env.development

```
REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE = 0
```

.env.production

```
REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE = 1
```

features.js

```js
const { REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE } = process.env
export default {
    IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE: REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE //
}
```

Now assuming this is in Development mode, when I do:

index.js

```js
import Features from "./features.js";
if(Features.IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE) {
    return (<div>Markup here!</div>)
};
```

But, regardless of what the value of `IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE` is, the `if` is always passing.

I did figured a way out of this, and its working well and good. But I am still confused why this wasn't working.

---

In response to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720488/8349557 here's what I tried:

[image: comparing 0 is equal to true or not]

Comment: What about using `Features.IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE`?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Was a typo.. doing `Features.IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE` only

Comment: yeah, I forgot `"0" == true` both values seem to get coerced to numbers ... so it becomes `0 == 1` - which is false ... but `"0"` is still truthy ... `!!"0"` is true, whereas `!!0` is false

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please update your answer, i'll mark it as correct. :D

Comment: I have  removed the `"0" == true` mistake :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at a guess, since "environment variables" in every OS I've worked with are always **strings** what you're essentially doing is

```
if("0")
```

And since any non-empty string is truthy, and true is truthy, the result is true

You can confirm this by

```js
console.log('!!"0" is', !!"0"); // true, therefore "0" is truthy
console.log('!!0 is', !!0); // false, therefore 0 is falsey
```

try

```
const { REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE } = process.env
export default {
    IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE: +REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE //
}
```

The `+` coerces the value to be a number

or, to make it CLEAR

```
const { REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE } = process.env
export default {
    IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE: "1" === REACT_APP_IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE //
}
```

Now IS_FEATURE_AVAILABLE is a boolean

Comment: Finally! An answer that might make sense! I thought about this at first. But when I do, `"0" === true` in the (browser's) console, it return `false`. Why would that be?

Comment: @AjayGupta - `===` is **strict** equals ... so `"0" === "0"` because they are exactly equal ... but `"0"` is not the same thing as `true` ... however `"0" == true` because both of them are "truthy" ... `if("0")` is equivalent to `if("0" == true)` not `if("0"===true)`

Comment: Haha! this is getting interesting :D

Comment: but `"0"` is truthy ... `!!"0"` vs `!!0` - I think there must be some coercion going on when you compare `"0" == true` ... ahh, yes ... true is coerced to `1` :p ... so `"0" == true` seems to become `0 == 1`

Comment: Totally makes sense.. Thanks!